# MySQL: Matching/filling a matrix with a list of ZIP Codes and IDs

Tags: mysql, dynamic-pivot

I'm trying to fill a table tbl_matrix. The first row contains unique IDs. The first column contains unique zip codes (5 integers).

The other table tbl_list contains three columns: 'zip_code', 'id', 'occurrence' (approx. 300000 rows).

Now I want to update/fill tbl_matrix with an algorithm/loop that checks if tbl_list contains the combination of a zip code and ID and returns the occurrence to tbl_matrix. In some cases the list contains two or more same combinations of zip_code and ID, but with different occurrence counts. In this case, the occurrences should be added up.

I'm using MySQL Workbench on a Windows machine and I'm not experienced with Perl/Python/PHP, so it would be great to solve the problem solely in MySQL.

In Excel I would use a vlookup function per column in tbl_matrix, but until now I couldn't adapt other similar (My)SQL examples from stackoverflow. It would be great if you could help me (its a college project).
Thank you so much, Lars.

Comment: it is not clear what you want. Should tbl_matrix  contain all unique  combinations of id, zip from the tbl_list?

Comment: Yes, the matrix should be filled with the sum of 'occurrence' of all unique combinations of ID and zip. But tbl_matrix already contains all possible IDs (first row) and zip codes (first column). The rest of tbl_matrix is empty.
I hope this answered your question.

Comment: then matrix has the field for `sum of 'occurrence'` ?

Comment: may be, you show the structure of matrix?

Comment: `select zip_code, id, sum(occurrence) from tbl_list group by zip_code, id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this can be an aproach to solve the problem

```
create table thetable (id int, zip_code int,  occurrence int);
insert into thetable values (1,1,1), (2,1,2), (1,2,3), (1,2,4);

select id, 
       sum(if(zip_code=1, sum, 0)) zip1,
       sum(if(zip_code=2, sum, 0)) zip2
     from 
       (select id, zip_code, sum(occurrence) sum 
           from tbl_list  
         group by id, zip_code
       ) t
     group by id
```

result

```
| id | zip1 | zip2 |
|----|------|------|
|  1 |    1 |    7 |
|  2 |    2 |    0 |
```

[**Demo on sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/427a6/6)

Comment: The OP probably wants dynamic columns; generating the same SQL using `GROUP_CONCAT`, as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26297463/111794) answer and executing the dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are looking to do is create a **dynamic pivot table** using MySQL (dynamic because you don't want to define the columns manually, but rather have them generated from some other source, in this case the unique zip codes). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26297463/111794).

Also note that in Excel it makes sense for the first row to be the unique ZIP codes, because you cannot change the column names (A, B, C etc.). In SQL, however, the column names can and should be the unique ZIP codes, so there is no need for a first row of ZIP codes.